# Link VF page to Button

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component

[image: AccountInfo]

How to give a VF page link to custom Button(In yellow Circle). My VF page Name is CreateUserPage.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: @v-t your VF page needs to use the standardController of the object , whose detail page you are trying to add the custom button.

Answer (score 1):

Set the button content source to 'Visualforce Page' and select your VF page, or set content type to 'URL' and redirect to '/apex/CreateUserPage?Id={!Account.Id}'